# Skip Submit button in array_keys

Tags: php, fputcsv

I've got a PHP routine that processes a form and outputs the values to a CSV file. I'm using `array_keys()` to create the header row (skipped if there is one). Everything works perfectly except the final header term is "submit" because, of course, my form includes a Submit button. So the data ends up looking like this:

```
name,email,cell,dob,study,submit
"Temp One",fred@gmail.com,646-325-1111,1995-03-31,8,Submit
"Temp Two",tom@gmail.com,646-325-2222,1995-03-31,4,Submit
```

How do I omit the submit button both from the header and the data?

Here's my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $data = array_values($_POST); // get only values
    $headers = array_keys($_POST); // keys are headers 
    if( $fp = fopen('data.csv','a+')) {
        $line = fgets($fp);
        if(!$line == $headers) {
                fputcsv($fp, $headers);
                fputcsv($fp, $data);
        }
        else
        {
            fputcsv($fp, $data);
        }
        fclose($fp);
        header('Location: thanks.php'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: There is some use in reading through the topics of the PHP manual when you plan to use the language a bit more. For example the section about variables and array: http://php.net/variables http://php.net/arrays

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove it from the array...

```
$post = $_POST;
unset($post['submit']);
$data = array_values($post); // get only values
$headers = array_keys($post); // keys are headers
```

Comment: nice one! therefor +1

Answer (score 1):

Drop the name from the Submit button in your html

and instead of

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

use

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_pop()` will remove the last element of an array:

```
$data = array_pop(array_values($_POST)); // get only values
$headers = array_pop(array_keys($_POST)); // keys are headers
```